# The video app on iPhone does not remember last watched position

Tags: iphone, video, ios

Is there any way to make the video on iPhone remember the last watched position of a movie?

If I stop watching at like 59:03, I expect the app to open the movie at 59:03 the next time I open the movie in the app. Apple TV does it, or really asks if you want to pick up where you left, or start from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to *Settings* → *Videos* and choose where to resume playback.

Comment: That is obvious, but how to auto-resume where left off ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 It does that automatically?

Comment: It's strange to hide this feature in settings...

Comment: In 2017 I cannot find this setting